# VBA Compiliation Error "Invalid Use Of Property"

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

I'm getting the "Invalid use of property" error on the function header line here:

```
Public Function process_station(ByVal station_id As String) As StationData
'Take a station id and return a StationData object with all of its tags from the server
    Dim curStation As New StationData: curStation.init_station station_id
    Dim srvTags As PointList: Set srvTags = srv.GetPoints("Tag = '*" & station_id & "*'")
    Dim curTag As TagString
    For Each t In srvTags
        Set curTag = New TagString: curTag.Data t.PathName
        curStation.addTag curTag
    Next t
    Set process_station = curStation
End Function
```

StationData is a custom class that's not having problems anywhere else. Am I setting up this function incorrectly? I'm assuming that the compilation error referring to the function header means that the problem is not within the actual function block, if that's incorrect I will explain the rest of the code.

This function is being called by another module with DataHandler.process_station. DataHandler is the module in which it resides.

Comment: It highlights the header but the error message clearly doesn't apply to the function definition. The definition ("header" as you call it) is fine. It's a wild guess but try separating the `curStation.init_station station_id` from the `dim line` - drop it onto a new line. Same applies to the line `Set curTag = new TagString...` -separate them. Make sure you're passing the right arguments to whatever class functions/properties you're calling.

Comment: Caught the error at curTag.Data, which is a property that I was using as a method for some reason. Just needed an operator. Thank you